# How to control an application from python script

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, interaction

I would like to control a windows program from a python script to automatise data extraction. I start by opening the program, but then I don't know how to interact with it to produce the output I want.

I call it as follows:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\GTPAg2\\gtapagg2.exe'])
```

The program I use (GTAPAG) is irrelevant, think as if I were opening any other program (i.e. a pdf reader) and wanted to control the actions it offers to the user.

Is there a way to see the available actions and run them?